# upload picture and video from camera

Tags: android

How to upload picture and video from camera or gallery to fb account in android?
can u please give me suggestion for to solve this problems.
I can post status in fb account using bellow code..

```
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", review);        
        params.putString("picture", "http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/6hqd44");
        mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST",
                new WallPostListener());
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try it -

Upload picture,

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();

 params.putByteArray("picture", <image in bytes>);
 params.putString("message", "Have fun");

 mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```

Upload video,

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

param.putString("filename", <dataName>);
param.putByteArray("video", <data in bytes>);

 mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```